# SOQL Difference Between two datetime columns

Tags: soql, datetime

I'm trying to find all records that have a difference of 5 years between two of their columns.

A mysql example of this would be

```
SELECT ...
FROM custom_object__c where mydatabase_ID__c > 1 and TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, start_date__c, end_date__c) >= 5
```

`start_date__c` is the starting date and `end_date__c` is my ending date so if the `end_date__c` is more than 5 years from `start_date__c` I want the record returned.

I haven't seen anything close to this functionality using a SOQL query. This https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gvhiAAA seemed close but that is for a formuala, not SOQL.

I could do this with PHP but iterating over every row is going to be resource intensive and I'd prefer to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible out of the box. The standard workaround is to use a formula, then filter on that:

```
WHERE Year_Range_Length__c >= 5
```

Please note that this behavior is covered in the `Force.com SOQL and SOSL Reference` documentation on **[fieldExpresion Syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fieldexpression.htm)** (emphasis mine):

> ```
>   fieldName comparisonOperator value
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **Syntax**
>   value
>
> **Description**
>   A value used to compare with the value in fieldName. You must supply a value whose data type matches the field type of the specified field. You must supply a native value—**other field names or calculations are not permitted**. If quotes are required (for example, they are not for dates and numbers), use single quotes. Double quotes result in an error.